# OpenGL Rapid Flickering Issues - and now not showing image

Tags: delphi, opengl, delphi-xe2, flicker

I'm having some troubles with OpenGL. First of all, I have a custom control which I'm building, encapsulating OpenGL. I'm having a problem where it rapidly flickers, like it's 'flashing'. The control was too large and complex to post here, so I made a new small demo app to demonstrate and recreate the same scenario.

The problem now: I'm not getting any image. Things would show fine in my custom control, but since I've copied the code and stripped it down in a small demo app, it won't show the image. So here I have two issues at hand: Flickering (or flashing), and now the image is not even showing. The flickering didn't occur in the past, but after some major code revision, it started flickering. It was too much code change to explain what exactly was changed, just about everything.

The background shows, so I know it's drawing something (it is colored). It should be drawing just a single cube for demo purposes, but I don't see anything. I had to strip this down from around 1,000 lines of code to not even 300.

It's not what you would normally call a flicker, it's actually more of a flashing, or blinking, imagine a car blinker flashing on and off. It definitely has to do with the timer, because the higher interval I put on the timer, the slower it flashes.

Why am I not seeing anything? And once this is fixed, why is it flickering so much?

Here's a single form's code, no DFM necessary:

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, Winapi.OpenGL,
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FDrawing: Bool;
    FDC: HDC;
    FRC: HGLRC;
    FDL: glUint;
    FTimer: TTimer;
    procedure Draw;
    procedure SetDC(const Value: HDC);
    procedure SetRC(const Value: HGLRC);
    procedure SetDL(const Value: glUint);
  public
    property DC: HDC read FDC write SetDC;
    property RC: HGLRC read FRC write SetRC;
    property DL: glUint read FDL write SetDL;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  PixelFormat: glUint;
  pfd: TPIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR;
begin
  FDrawing := False;
  FDC := GetDC(Handle);
  with pfd do begin
    nSize := SizeOf(TPIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    nVersion := 1; // The version of this data structure
    dwFlags := PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW // Buffer supports drawing to window
      or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL // Buffer supports OpenGL drawing
      or PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER; // Supports double buffering
    iPixelType := PFD_TYPE_RGBA; // RGBA color format
    cColorBits := 32; // OpenGL color depth
    cRedBits := 0; // Number of red bitplanes
    cRedShift := 0; // Shift count for red bitplanes
    cGreenBits := 0; // Number of green bitplanes
    cGreenShift := 0; // Shift count for green bitplanes
    cBlueBits := 0; // Number of blue bitplanes
    cBlueShift := 0; // Shift count for blue bitplanes
    cAlphaBits := 0; // Not supported
    cAlphaShift := 0; // Not supported
    cAccumBits := 0; // No accumulation buffer
    cAccumRedBits := 0; // Number of red bits in a-buffer
    cAccumGreenBits := 0; // Number of green bits in a-buffer
    cAccumBlueBits := 0; // Number of blue bits in a-buffer
    cAccumAlphaBits := 0; // Number of alpha bits in a-buffer
    cDepthBits := 16; // Specifies the depth of the depth buffer
    cStencilBits := 0; // Turn off stencil buffer
    cAuxBuffers := 0; // Not supported
    iLayerType := PFD_MAIN_PLANE; // Ignored
    bReserved := 0; // Number of overlay and underlay planes
    dwLayerMask := 0; // Ignored
    dwVisibleMask := 0; // Transparent color of underlay plane
    dwDamageMask := 0; // Ignored
  end;
  PixelFormat := ChoosePixelFormat(FDC, @pfd);
  SetPixelFormat(FDC, PixelFormat, @pfd);
  FRC := wglCreateContext(FDC);
  wglMakeCurrent(FDC, FRC);
  FormResize(nil);
  wglMakeCurrent(FDC, FRC);
  glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.0);
  glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
  glClearDepth(1.0);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
  glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
  glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.4);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glNewList(FDL, GL_COMPILE);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      // Front Face
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      // Back Face
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, -1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, 1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, 1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, -1.0, -1.0);
      // Top Face
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, 1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, 1.0, -1.0);
      // Bottom Face
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, -1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, -1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      // Left Face
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, -1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glEnd();
  glEndList();
  FTimer:= TTimer.Create(nil);
  FTimer.OnTimer:= Timer1Timer;
  FTimer.Interval:= 100;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FTimer.Free;
  if (not wglMakeCurrent(FDC, 0)) then
    MessageBox(0, 'Release of DC and RC failed!', 'Error', MB_OK or MB_ICONERROR);
  if (not wglDeleteContext(FRC)) then begin
    MessageBox(0, 'Release of rendering context failed!', 'Error', MB_OK or MB_ICONERROR);
    FRC := 0;
  end;
  if ((FDC > 0) and (ReleaseDC(Handle, FDC) = 0)) then begin
    MessageBox(0, 'Release of device context failed!', 'Error', MB_OK or MB_ICONERROR);
    FDC := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Draw;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if not FDrawing then begin
    FDrawing := TRUE;
    try
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
      glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
      glCullFace(GL_BACK);
      glLoadIdentity;
      glPushMatrix();
      glCallList(DL);
      glPopMatrix();
      SwapBuffers(wglGetCurrentDC);
    finally
      FDrawing := False;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluPerspective(45.0, Width / Height, 0.1, 500.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
end;

procedure TForm1.SetDC(const Value: HDC);
begin
  FDC := Value;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetDL(const Value: glUint);
begin
  FDL := Value;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetRC(const Value: HGLRC);
begin
  FRC := Value;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Draw;
end;

end.
```

Now the above code is rather far different from how my original code works. The original `Draw` procedure does an iteration through a list of objects, each object containing its own `Draw` procedure. So the control's draw procedure prepares the overall scene, then draws each 'item' one by one, like this:

```
procedure TGLImage.Draw;
var
  X: Integer;
begin
  if not FDrawing then begin
    FDrawing := TRUE;
    try
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
      glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
      glCullFace(GL_BACK);
      glLoadIdentity();

      glRotatef(FElapsedTime / 70, 0, 0, 1);
      glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
      glTranslatef(-FElapsedTime / 400, 0, 0);

      if FInitialized then begin
        for X := 0 to FItems.Count - 1 do begin
          FItems[X].Draw;
        end;
      end;

      SwapBuffers(wglGetCurrentDC);
    finally
      FDrawing := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And here's one of the items it draws...

```
constructor TGLBeam.Create(AOwner: TGLItems);
begin
  inherited;
  glNewList(DL, GL_COMPILE);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      // Front Face
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      // Back Face
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, -1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, 1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, 1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, -1.0, -1.0);
      // Top Face
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, 1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, 1.0, -1.0);
      // Bottom Face
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, -1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, -1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(2.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(-2.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      // Left Face
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, -1.0, -1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3f(2.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glEnd();
  glEndList();
end;

procedure TGLBeam.Draw;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  glRotatef(Directions.X, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glRotatef(Directions.Y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glRotatef(Directions.Z, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  for I := 1 to 10 do begin
    //Main Center
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(I * 4 + Owner.Owner.ClockTime * 4, 0, 0);
    glCallList(DL);
    glPopMatrix();
    //Above
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(I * 4 + Owner.Owner.ClockTime * 4, 6, 0);
    glCallList(DL);
    glPopMatrix();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: As a general rule in Windows programming, you should never do any output to a `DC` (device context) except in response to the `WM_PAINT` message (Delphi's `OnPaint` event). Both issues are probably caused by your code fighting with Window's default drawing. You can probably fix this by moving all of your drawing code to the `OnPaint` event handler (or simply moving the call to `Draw` to that event).

Comment: @KenWhite Just tried, but that made it even worse. It used to work just fine using the timer method, smooth and no flicker. Now it's like as soon as it finishes drawing, it immediately clears what it drew.

Comment: The VCL uses double-buffering (drawing to an off-screen bitmap, and then updating the entire surface at once by copying that bitmap) to avoid flickering. Not an OpenGL guy myself, but you might look into doing the same. I'm sure some of the open-source code has a demo you can use as a start. Maybe Rodrigo (@RRUZ) will stop by; I think he's got pretty good knowledge of OpenGL IIRC.

Comment: Thanks, actually DoubleBuffered is the first thing I tried, and had no success.

Comment: I didn't say to *use* `DoubleBuffered` as implemented on `TForm`. I suggested looking for an OpenGL example of doing the same thing. :)

Comment: Ahhh... I see what you mean, yes I use this method in many of my controls, just haven't done it in this one. Good idea, but don't think that is the actual issue. There's something going on which seems to clear the image right after it's drawn.

Comment: Is it possible to get a copy of the source? I feel some of the flow is being lost in moving it to here.

Comment: Wait you are setting your `gluLookAt` right?

Comment: Original source: http://www.sendspace.com/file/5lhqdi - I had posted it earlier in another question (deleted) but it was evidently not proper to post links to outside sources, which prompted me to make this washed down version above.

Comment: I never ever link to NeHe, but at least he has Delphi ports of his tutorials : http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/your_first_polygon/13002/ . Sorry I can't help more, I don't know anything about Delphi.

Comment: New question about using OpenGL inside a thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746616/performing-opengl-drawing-from-within-a-thread

Comment: Answer discovered, huge mistake, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the flickering was has been discovered, and it was a very huge mistake that I don't expect you to have figured out without having the entire project. The problem was that I was creating **TWO** of these controls, and they were interfering / fighting with each other. Actually, because OpenGL works on a thread-by-thread basis (or within one 'context'), having two different controls which are trying to do their own drawing will interfere - causing the same thing to occur on both controls at the same time. So the flashing was from the fact that each control was trying to take turns doing the drawing. My new question which I have asked related to putting this drawing inside of a Thread will perfectly cure for this issue. It was a dumb mistake and I'm sorry for wasting anyone's time.

Answer (score 2):

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glLoadIdentity;
glPushMatrix();
glCallList(DL);
glPopMatrix();
SwapBuffers(wglGetCurrentDC);
```

<strike>Firstly add the () to your call to `glLoadIdentity`</strike>

You loading the identity matrix then pushing it then rendering and popping it without actually doing any transformations.

Either remove the 3 lines

```
glLoadIdentity;
glPushMatrix();

glPopMatrix();
```

or move the `glPushMatrix()` to the line before the `glLoadIdentity()`

I would also suggest turning off shading and culling just to make sure they aren't interfering. Quads being declared in a slightly wrong order with backface culling on just culls them even when you don't want them culled from in front.

Comment: Yep. :) Comment removed. Edited to <strike>strike out</strike> remark about adding `()`; the parentheses are optional in Delphi when no parameters are required.

Comment: Easier said than done, considering the original code - `glLoadIdentity` is in one place and the other two are in a far different place, a different unit actually. Original code actually does much more after `glLoadIdentity` and in-between the other 2. I'm trying to move these lines of code around to see the results.....

Comment: Tried this, and it did not work, it doesn't even show the drawing now. I've added some original code to demonstrate how this control actually works. Each item's Draw procedure draws an individual object in the scene.