# Performing OpenGL Drawing from within a Thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, opengl, custom-controls, delphi-xe2

I've been wrapping the core OpenGL functionality within a Delphi VCL custom control. Currently, I am doing a loop using a `TTimer` created within this control. I strongly feel using a timer is completely wrong, as drawing could both overlap and have delays. Instead, I would like to put this drawing loop within a thread. Please refer to my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729526/opengl-rapid-flickering-issues-and-now-not-showing-image) with some issues of flickering - which I'm putting the blame on the `TTimer` which I'm using.

**Question**

Is OpenGL safe to use inside of a thread? What should I be aware of? I plan on making OpenGL API calls from both inside and outside of this thread. It will essentially be a continuous loop, where as soon as it's finished drawing, it will immediately start drawing again. Currently, using a Timer, it depends on waiting for the Timer's interval to be reached. So, for example, if the Timer's interval is set to 100 msec, and the drawing only takes 20 msec, then there will be 80 msec of waiting until it draws again. Using a thread will eliminate this delay. How should I make such calls from inside this thread?

**Background**

The original sample project which I based all of my API calls off of was using the application's main thread, and in fact used absolutely no VCL at all. The Window which displayed the image was dynamically created using pure Windows API calls, and the drawing was repeated from within a continuous loop in the application's main thread. This is why I believe using a Thread will solve many of my issues - specifically the flickering.

Comment: Just to clarify - if you're using the `Forms` unit anywhere, you're using the VCL. If you're creating any form in any way than direct WinAPI calls (`RegisterClass` and `CreateWindow`), you're using the VCL. If you're using the VCL, drawing from a thread on anything in the VCL is not thread-safe. Your original code (linked above) references at least five units (Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls) that are the VCL - note the `Vcl` namespace.

Comment: That's not the original original - before that it was a demo app I downloaded from somewhere which was all coded in the project file, no forms - and the form was created/destroyed using pure Windows API.

Comment: This will help you: http://www.google.com/m?q=opengl+draw+thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One OpenGL context can only be current (active) in one given thread. So either you have to unbind/rebind the current context correctly in your threads, or you have to use two context sharing data. I strongly recommend to restructure your design to only use a single thread doing OpenGL call. More background can be found at http://www.equalizergraphics.com/documentation/parallelOpenGLFAQ.html.

Comment: +1 So, theoretically, I could do ALL my OpenGL calls from within this one thread, and none outside of it... right? Does it require any type of thread initialization, such as `CoInitialize()`?

Comment: Yes, correct. OpenGL does not need any thread initialization, but other libraries might, e.g., XInitThreads on Unix.